# Give an example of a compact countable infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Give an example of a compact countable infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  I'm having a difficult time, because I know that closed intervals $[a,b]$ are compact and infinite but are uncountable.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded? Can you find an example of a countable set which is closed and bounded?

Comment: Once one is aware of the example of a convergent sequence and its limit, an interesting follow-up is trying to understand what countable linear orders are possible as compact countable subsets of ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Thank you! So for instance an example would be: Let (sn)=1/n. Then it would be {1/n U 0}?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Is it clear to you why this is compact?

Comment: @Andres, is there a reasonable way to characterize such linear orders?

Comment: Yes it is closed because it contains all the limit points and bounded since it is bounded below by 0 and above by 1.  Then any closed and bounded subset of R^n is compact.

Comment: @Alon: I know of partial results, but not a full answer. I think it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 8):

Try a convergent sequence together with its limit point.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$